# Unobtrusive credit card validation not working once deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm running MVC4 and .NET 4.5. I applied the data annotations credit card validator to my model. I'm having issues with the client side validation. It works fine on my development box, but once deployed to production, it doesn't work.

When viewing source on my dev box, I get this:

```
<input data-bind="value: creditCardNumber" data-val="true" data-val-creditcard="Credit Card Number is invalid." data-val-length="Credit Card Number must be less than 20 characters." data-val-length-max="20" data-val-required="Credit Card Number is required." id="CreditCardNumber" name="CreditCardNumber" value="" type="text">
```

On my production box, I get this:

```
<input data-bind="value: creditCardNumber" data-val="true" data-val-length="Credit Card Number must be less than 20 characters." data-val-length-max="20" data-val-required="Credit Card Number is required." id="CreditCardNumber" name="CreditCardNumber" value="" type="text">
```

The difference between the two is that the production system is missing:

```
data-val-creditcard="Credit Card Number is invalid."
```

Any ideas? The server side validation works, but not the client side.

Thanks,
Vincent